# How can i add userID into firebase database, Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am developing an events app in which users can add themselves into prexisting events.

[image: App:]

When +Add me is clicked the userID will be added to the database.

[image: Firebase DB]

I have an adapter and POJO class linking the UI. But I am confused as to where the .setValue() command should do.
I have put it inside the adapter and it just sends the member id to the first child.

```
public static class EventViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    FirebaseUser current_user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    String uid = current_user.getUid();
    DatabaseReference myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Members").child(uid);
 DatabaseReference eventRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Events").child("lists");

        public EventViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

        addMe = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.add_me);

        addMe.setOnClickListener(this);

        @Override
        public void onClick(final View v) {
            if (v.getId() == addMe.getId()) {


                myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        final String uName = dataSnapshot.child("member").getValue().toString();
                        addMe.setText(uName);

                        int position = 0;

                        eventRef.child(mListl.get(position).getId()).child("members").setValue(uid);

                        Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                            .make(v, "You have been added to the event!", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .setAction("- Remove me", new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(final View view) {

                                    Snackbar snackbar1 = Snackbar.make(v, "You have been removed from the event!", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
                                    snackbar1.show();
                                }
                            });

                        snackbar.show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });

            }

        }
    }
```

The above piece of code just adds the UID into the first node.
[image: Database]

I'm not sure if I'm using the right approach or right code. I just want multiple users to be able to click on +add me, which in turn would add them inside a child node 'members' But most importantly, only to the event which they have clicked +add me in the card view.
Hope I am making myself clear. 
Would really appreciate some help to my particular problem.

[image: Member's DB]

I would assume i would have to eventually use a hashmap of sorts, but i just want to see if im on the right track.

Comment: What you want to do. As per my understandings of your question, you have events and people can be add themselves in the event when clicked on add me. And you want to save it as the member in that event. Currently you added it the list test and it has been added as a memeber. What you want yo acheive?

Comment: what actually is your problem i did not understand your questions, can you be more clear

Comment: @MalikAhsan yes that's right, when the users clicks on the specific card they need to get added as member in the corresponding database, but now only the top level dB get the member node no matter which card +add me is clicked in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a workaround which enabled me to gather the userID:

On a really high level:

I attached a textbox and kept its value as hidden,

upon clicking I gathered the userid from the ui and fired it into firebase dtabase !